# How can I connect two outlook accounts?

Tags: outlook

I have two outlook mail accounts, as an example a and b. I successfully connected them in a account. I can get b accounts mails in a account. But when I delete b account mail from a account, it is only deleting on a. I want outlook to delete the mail from b account too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, new outlook "connected accounts" doesnt let you deleting mails from the source.